# Rails views: join on has_many relations instead of iterating through them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, view, relationship

Rails views: join on objects

Hi,

think of the show view of the model User that has a has_many relationship with the model Role. I want to iterate through all associated Roles that belong to a certain User. Right now it looks like this:

```
<div>associated roles:</div>
<ul>
<% @user.roles.each do |r| %>
<li><%= r.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

which results for example in:

```
associated roles:
* registered
* manager
* administrator
```

My question:

Is there a Rails-like way of getting an output like the following without having to iterate through the whole array?

```
associated roles:
registered, manager, administrator
```

I tried the join method ...

```
<div>associated roles:</div>
<%= @user.roles.join(",") %>
```

... but that results in ...

```
associated roles:
#<Role:0xb6dde328>,#<Role:0xb6dde2ec>,#<Role:0xb6dde1f5>
```

And something like ...

```
<div>associated roles:</div>
<%= @user.roles.join(",").name %>
```

... results in an undefined method `name' error.
Any hints for an elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@user.roles.collect(&:name).join(",")
```

Comment: Another solution is to override to_s in the Role class